# PHP/HTML table with separate columns

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to build a table in PHP/HTML where the data is being pulled from a db and being displayed on the website...my only problem is I want each column to be separate and have its own search function and when a user clicks on a field, I want the other columns to reflect the same row information like below: 
My question is: how would I be able to do something like this?  I have tried breaking it into different tables and then joining them but that did not work.

Link to example:

[image]

Code example I am using:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
         <th>Firstname</th>
         <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Nice, so what have you tried? Give us some code you have already worked on. Do you have a question to go along with this? We can't work with you unless you give us a question and some relevant code that you have tried because we will not write your code for you.

Comment: Hi @BuddhistBeast I do not want someone to write the code, just some guidance. I posted an example from W3Schools as I am still learning. For the column filtering I am working towards using something like the example on http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tablefilter.shtml

Comment: What I have tried before is to do like a nested table within the while loop. I do not have that code anymore because it did not work

Answer (score 1):

To populate different tables with different information, try....well okay, say you have 3 tables you want to show data in.

> [ tbl1 / tbl2 / tbl3 ]

First set up 3 php variables that will hold the queries to the database.
(pseudo code)(to give you an idea)

```
$tblData1 = Select query here;
$tblGETdata1 = mysqli_query( your connect var here, $tblData1 )

$tblData2 = Select query here;
$tblGETdata2 = mysqli_query( your connect var here, $tblData3 )

$tblData3 = Select query here;
$tblGETdata3 = mysqli_query( your connect var here, $tblData3 )
```

Then setup while loops that looks for data on any of these above.
for example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(tblGETdata1 )){
//output your echoed table content here;
}


while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array(tblGETdata2 )){
//output your echoed table content here;
}



while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array(tblGETdata3 )){
//output your echoed table content here;
}
```

or if you dont want to get messy with the echoing of your tables, you can structure it like so:

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(tblGETdata3 )){ ?>


<!-- put your normal HTML here. For example if your fetch has a first name you can do -->
<div class="firstName">This persons first name is: <?php echo $row['firstName']; ?> </div>

<?php
   }
?>
```

Youd Style this of course as youd like for desired effect.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi @somdow, this is good if I wanted 3 different tables with different data but, What I am looking for instance is 1 table 3 columns. These 3 columns would show the data from the same table, but each column is separated in a sense where each can function independently until the user selects 1 cell from 1 of the columns. Once the user clicks on that cell, the other columns should reflect the row information of the cell that was selected. Not sure if you have tried using qlikview desktop but I am trying to get the same done, just for a browser.